# Strange characters in a function with pyspark

Tags: text, unicode, pyspark

I'm trying to understand how PySpark works with strange characters (for example Spanish accents).
If I put

```
print 'áááájgmdkfk'
```

It works and print

Áááájgmdkfk

But, if I define a function with strange characters, I get an error:

```
def dummy():
    print 'áááájgmdkfk'

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Does anyone know why I can't use strange characters in a function?

Comment: Is `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in effect? Because otherwise you should use the u-prefix notation to get unicode strings (`u'áááájgmdkfk'`). Apart from that, there's not enough context for me to guess why it would work outside a function, but not inside.

Comment: What is the output of
`import sys`
`sys.getdefaultencoding()`